Fundamental theorem of Markov chains for integrable functions
Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an irreducible, positive recurrent and aperiodic Markov chain on a countable set $E$, with stationary distribution $\pi$. Let $f\in L^1(\pi)$. Is it true that $P^nf(x):=E_x[f(X_n)]\to \pi(f)$ almost surely (i.e. for $\pi$-a.e. $x\in E$) as $n\to \infty$?
I know that the answer is positive if $f$ is bounded, and I am able to prove that if $f\in L^1$ then $P^nf\to \pi(f)$ in $L^1(\pi)$, but here I am interested in the almost sure convergence for a general $f\in L^1$.

The notion of "convergence almost surely" is used for sequences of random variables, rather than sequences of real numbers.  For example, for simplicity suppose $f$ is bounded. Fix $x \in E$ and define $a_n=E[f(X_n)|X_0=x]$. Then ${a_n}{n=0}^{\infty}$ is just a sequence of real numbers and it either converges or does not, it is unusual to talk about it converging "almost surely" or "in L1." What did you mean when you said these real numbers converge "in L1"? Do you really want to ask if $\frac{1}{n}\sum{i=1}^nf(X_i)$ congerges almost surely and/or in L1?

@Michael No, I don't want to ask whether $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$ converges almost surely or in $L^1$ (that's the content of the ergodic theorem and is fine). What I want to ask is whether for $\pi$-almost every $x\in E$ it holds that $P^nf(x)\to \pi(f)$. Similarly, when I speak of $L^1$ convergence, I mean that $\int_E |P^nf(x)-\pi(f)|d\pi(x)\to 0$.

If $\pi(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in E$, and you know there is a real number $c$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{x \in E} |E[f(X_n)|X_1=x]-c|\pi(x)=0$$ then for all $x \in E$ such that $\pi(x)>0$ we know $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |E[f(X_n)|X_1=x]-c|=0$.

Of course, in your case, since $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution for the irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent DTMC with countable state space $E$, we know $\pi(x)>0$ for all $x\in E$.

@Michael You are right, thank you! It was much more trivial than what I expected.
